# Почему at не запускает скрипт в определенное время?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, sh, at

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так. 
Есть скрипт с простым кодом:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "text"
```

Пытаюсь запустить этот скрипт с помощью at:

```
./script | at 20:06
```

Когда наступает это время, ничего не происходит, хотя скрипт рабочий и запускается. Не работает что в sh, что в bash. Что не так делаю? Почему не выводится текст?

Comment: Почему же ничего? Наверняка происходит попытка выполнить команду `text`. Попробуйте `echo ./script | at 20:06`. Только не ждите, что она напечатает что-то в консоль.

Comment: а почему не ждите? Эхо же должно вывести что-то в консоль или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: Должно, но не в вашу консоль, потому, что не в ней выполнится. результат скорее всего будет в почте рута или основного пользователя.

Answer (score 2):

фактически вы выполнили такую команду:

```
$ echo "text" | at время
```

вот в указанное время *atd* и попытается создать новую сессию от имени вашего пользователя и выполнить команду `test`.

эта (скорее всего у вас — встроенная в оболочку) команда ничего не выведет в *stdout* (так и должно быть — если ей не указано никаких параметров), поэтому *atd* (по умолчанию) больше ничего делать и не будет. а если бы выполняемая команда что-нибудь вывела в *stdout*/*stderr*, то эта информация была отправлена почтовым сообщением пользователю, создавшему это задание.

---

для проверки работоспособности *atd* и возможности создания заданий я бы рекомендовал что-нибудь вроде:

```
$ echo "touch /tmp/файл" | at "now+1min"
```

если «всё хорошо», то в первых секундах следующей минуты будет выполнена команда

```
$ touch /tmp/файл
```

и этот файл должен появиться (если до этого не существовал).

---

похожий вопрос: [Why does this 'at' command not print to the standard output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82835/110559)